# Not getting value from segue swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I got data from list and using `didSelectRowAt indexPath` with segue, I want to transfer data into map which is in another class. The code is still getting the data from selecting the row but when I transfer to another class it is showing `nil`.

Here's the prepare segue from my main view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Set selected location to var
    selectedLocation = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel
    // Manually call segue to detail view controller
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    let detailVC  = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
    // Set the property to the selected location so when the view for
    // detail view controller loads, it can access that property to get the feeditem obj
    detailVC.selectedLocation = selectedLocation
}
```

And here's the sub class:

```
class LocationModel: NSObject {

//properties

var name: String?
var address: String?
var latitude: String?
var longitude: String?


//empty constructor

override init()
{

}

//construct with @name, @address, @latitude, and @longitude parameters

init(name: String, address: String, latitude: String, longitude: String) {

    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude

}


//prints object's current state

override var description: String {
    return "Name: \(name), Address: \(address), Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude)"

}


}
```

Then I'm setting the data here:

```
class DetailViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var selectedLocation : LocationModel?
```

Comment: Comments have been [archived in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154330/discussion-on-question-by-pen-rueda-not-getting-value-from-segue-swift-3). **If you are asked for additional information and/or code, [edit] it into your question.** Do not include it in the comments.

Comment: Please check that `viewDidLoad()` of the `DetailViewController` is called after you do `detailVC.selectedLocation = selectedLocation` (you can add prints) If that's not the case, remove the segue, redo it, but from the viewcontroller and not the UITableViewCell to the `DetailViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Set selected location to var
    selectedLocation = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! LocationModel
    // Manually call segue to detail view controller
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: selectedLocation)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let detailVC  = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
    detailVC.selectedLocation = sender as! LocationModel 
}
```

Comment: the result from Print (selectedLocation) in prepareForSegue is here `Name: nil, Address: nil, Latitude: nil, Longitude: nil
Name: Optional("Store Name"), Address: Optional("City, state "), Latitude: Optional("24.41212"), Longitude: Optional("54.435422")
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this delegate:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    guard let _ = selectedLocation else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

If this doesn't work, I'd like to see more code.

Comment: Can you mail me the project please? I'd like to see what exactly is happening